# php mod_rewrite querystrings into real words

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a query string `mysite.com/?local=1` local varies from 1 - 600.

For each local is a city name. How can I rewrite the url so that it appears `mysite.com/cityname/`. I do not mind writing a scenario for each such as if (local ==1){cityname = boston;}.

Is what I'm asking for even possible? So I'd like to take `mysite.com/?local=1` and turn it into `mysite.com/boston/`.

Comment: Which URL do you want the user to type in / see in their address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php:

```
<?php
$map = array(
    1 => 'city',
    2 => 'Portland',
    3 => 'Kaunas',
    4 => 'Hokaido',
    .....
);
if (isset($_GET['local']) && intval($_GET['local']) < 600 && intval($_GET['local']) > 0) {
    header('Location: mysite.com/' . $map[intval($_GET['local'])]);
    die(); // Redirect to use the pretty url
}
$path = explode('/', explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[0]); // might need to expand if php version < 5.4
$city = $path[1];
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Basically what this combo does is if a GET string with variable 'local' is passed it will do a redirect with the city id converted to a name. After that you just take the query string and do whatever you want with it

Answer (score 0):

If you want the URL to actually change in the browser, you need a redirect and not a rewrite. In this case, you can just look up the name from the number and use `header("Location...");` as necessary.

Comment: My Script functions off the post, i just wanted to mask it with the actual city name, like taking a productID from a database and inserting the product name instead. id even settle for mysite.com/local/1/boston.html or anything of the sort